# child process not generating core file

Tags: process, segmentation-fault, core-file

I have a couple of process running through the init system. They're all forked by process A.

So in my init script, I have something like this:

```
ulimit -c unlimited
cd /usr/bin/ && ./proc_A
```

proc_A will then fork proc_B and proc_C, etc.

When proc_A causes a segfault, a core file will be dumped into /usr/bin. But this is not the case for proc_B and proc_C. Why?

Answer (score 0):

Actually first thing a child process does is chdir("/") and root is not writable. Mystery solved.